Tag wiki suggested edits
I just ran into a problem. On main, the tags exploit and crackme were created, but with spelling errors. The suggested edit approval page didn't show the name of the tag wiki and it was impossible to improve the edit.
In general the edits were good, but both have spelling errors which I wanted to correct. Alas, no cigar. More approvals are required before it becomes visible and I may well forget about it until then.
Any suggestions? Does it make sense to suggest this as improvement to the SO/SE staff?

I dont see any tags that are spelled similarly to [tag:exploit] or [tag:crackme]. Where do you see them?

@AsheeshR: The problem is not that the tags were misspelled. There were spelling issues in those (then newly created) tag wikis. I was one of the reviewers. But neither did the review show which tag wiki it was (or I missed it) nor did it let me correct as is usually the case for new posts. Probably because it was to be reviewed under "suggested edits"?

@AsheeshR: of course it's also possible I didn't bring that across very well ;)

Could you do another tag wiki (body not excerpt) edit?

You get the privilege to approve tag wiki edits at 1500 reputation. You get the privilege to edit tag wikis without supervision at 4000 reputation.
When you use “Improve” on a suggested edit, your version takes effect immediately without further review. If you have between 1500 and 4000 reputation, you can only approve or reject an edit, you cannot submit your own modifed version. Therefore you don't get an “Improve” button.
If you see an imperfect suggestion, wait until it is approved or rejected, then come back and make your own submission.

Er, you mean approved or rejected, right?

@SamB Yes. Fixed, thanks.
